# Heroku: Help Resolve Tesseract libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: heroku, tesseract

For Heroku's 18 stack what is the correct build pack to install [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)?  I have installed [this build pack](https://github.com/oswellchan/heroku-buildpack-tesseract), but whenever I use the `tesseract` binary I get the following error:

```
$ heroku run tesseract --version
tesseract: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Or is the problem something else and not with the build pack I am using?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem and continue using heroku 18 stack I had to choose a heroku [build pack](https://github.com/pathwaysmedical/heroku-buildpack-tesseract) which installed a more current version -- 4.0 -- of Tesseract.